# Problems with views when reloading fragment

Tags: android

this is bit when i'm creating view,

```
public static int a=0;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           a++;
           View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
           editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.amount);
           TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
           Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.addTransaction);
           button.setOnClickListener(this); ///fragments implements OnClickListener 
           editText.setText(""+a);
           tv.setText(""+a);
           return view;
        }
```

when i load this fragment first time, my editText is empty, but when i load fragment again, value in the editText is same like in previous execution.

Is anyone has idea what i'm doing wrong? And how i can fix it?

---

** EDIT

i modified little bit my code, now each time when i'm loading fragment a is incremented. and io noticed weird behaviour. tv has has actual value of a, while editText still has old value

Comment: How are you "loading" the fragment?

Comment: im using this code `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frag_content, newFragment).setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE).commit()` is it matter how i'm loading fragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the settext ( and probably some other stuff) into a later method in the fragment life cycle e.g. onActivityCreated.

Comment: i tried move to `onActivityCreated` and i had same issues, when i moved to `onStart` problem was solved. but what puzzles me is why behaviour for EditText is different from TextView

Comment: OK ... I have lots of settext and findViewById stuff in onActivityCreated - I don't currently use editText in my app though.

Answer (score 1):

Before adding the fragment try to get the fragment by calling FindFragmentByTag("tag"), i think you are adding new fragments on top of each other. Also add your fragment transaction to back state and then to check if more than one fragments are added, press back button. I had similar problem, and the reason was i kept adding new fragments in activity

Comment: souinds reasonable, i thought for moment same, because it looks like that, but first i'm doing `replace` not `add` and second when i do `findFragmentByTag` i'm getting null, and it means fragment is not there

Answer (score 0):

Fragments are tied to activities, so my guess is that the activity is not being destroyed, which means your fragment is not being destroyed and instead "resumed". Perhaps you want that code in the `onResume` callback? Take a look at the Fragment lifecycle: [Android Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)